# How do I specify the server address for the .NET Business Connector installation?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm trying to install the .NET Business Connector for Dynamics AX 2012 R3 but during the installation I get an error message indicating that the AOS cannot be reached. The server mentioned in the error message does not exist.

How can I tell the setup it should use a different server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be: The registry

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Configuration\Original (installed configuration)

Value "aos2"

I've changed that to the correct value and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

From the TechNet page [Install the .NET Business Connector AX 2012](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa548683.aspx)

> 11. On the **Connect to an AOS instance** page, enter the name of the computer that runs the instance of Application Object Server (AOS)
>       that you want to connect to. You can optionally specify the name of
>       the AOS instance, the TCP/IP port number, and the WSDL port for
>       services. Click **Next**.

Comment: The note below that text in TechNet explains that: "If you entered information about the AOS connection for other Microsoft Dynamics AX components that are installed on this computer, this page is not displayed. Subsequent installations on the same computer reuse the existing AOS connection."